# Looping makefile with multiple main functions

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile that can create one executable per main function.

I have a list of files: `main1.cpp`, `main2.cpp`, and `main3.cpp`. They each contain an `int main()` function. Obviously I can't build these into one exec, which is not the goal here, so how can I build each one of these into its own executable? This is one solution:

```
main1: main1.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
main2: main2.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
main3: main3.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

But there MUST be a better way to do this. Is there some type of looping feature to makefiles that will make this process easier? Like a for loop?

Comment: Even though gnu figures this out from the file extension, `$(CC)` is the c compiler.  You actually probably mean `$(CXX)` for C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mixture of `wildcard`, `patsubst` and [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), plus the standard make variables for C++ compilation and linking:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard main*.cpp)
EXES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(SRCS))

$(EXES): %: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDLIBS)
```

But as make knows already how to make all this you could as well get rid of your Makefile and just type `make main1`...

Comment: How can I make the SRCS wildcard recursively loop through an entire src folder?

Comment: What do you mean by _loop_? Consider all contained source files? This is already what `wildcard` does. Descend into sub-directories? If yes, where do you want to store the executables? In the same directory as the source file? Elsewhere? (if elsewhere be careful: you must avoid name conflicts)

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a very sophisticated makefile, your solution is fine for three simple programs.  You could make it more generic and support building all three targets at the same time with an "all" target.

```
all: main1 main2 main3
main1: main1.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
main2: main2.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
main3: main3.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```